# Can't reinstall apache2 - Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: server, apache2

I have uninstalled apache2 with these commands :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

I have found what is left with this command :

`whereis apache2`

And then deleted all of these files and directories.

Now when I tried to install apache2 and run it I got an error :

```
sudo apt install apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-10-03 10:34:31 UTC; 2min 38s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 12449 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[12449]: apache2.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[12449]: apache2.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: No such file or directory
Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 03 10:34:31 machina systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-09-28T11:00:45
```

```
apache2ctl -S

Command 'apache2ctl' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install apache2
Please ask your administrator.
```

Then I do :
`sudo apt install apache2`

But I get same error.

Tried this :

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2-bin`

Same error.

Comment: There may be a more specific message with actionable information about what failed in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` 

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this problem.

At first you need to stop the Apache2 service and uninstall it completely :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

After that **restart your machine** and only then install Apache2 again :

`sudo apt install apache2`